# Consume restful webservice through web proxy

Tags: java, rest, webproxy

I'm trying to consume a restful webservice in java using the [Apache Wink framework](http://incubator.apache.org/wink/) through my school web proxy requiring authentification

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.proxyHost("proxy.school.com");
clientConfig.proxyPort(3128);
//nothing to set username and password :(

RestClient client = new RestClient(clientConfig);
Resource resource = client.resource("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/artist/videos.xml");
String response = resource.accept("text/plain").get(String.class);
```

I've also tried to use the `BasicAuthSecurityHandler` but it seems to be used to authenticate directly to a web server, not the web proxy

```
BasicAuthSecurityHandler basicAuthHandler = new BasicAuthSecurityHandler();
basicAuthHandler.setUserName("username");
basicAuthHandler.setPassword("password");
config.handlers(basicAuthHandler);
```

It still fail with a HTTP 407 error code : Proxy Authentication Required.

I've googled the best I could, nothing came up better to consume a webservice from a Java client through a web proxy, if someone has another idea, feel free to respond

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok that was pretty hard but I found it ! I logged the HTTP requests that were being made from my browser with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and found out that the `Proxy-Connection` and `Proxy-Authorization` were what I was looking for after reading extensive documentation like [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) about HTTP/1.1

So I copy-pasted the values that were being sent into my java code :

```
resource.header("Proxy-Connection", "Keep-Alive");
resource.header("Proxy-Authorization", "Basic encodedString");
```

where `encodedString` is what is being sent by my browser : `username:password` base64 encoded

And it now works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

This issue was raised as [1] and has since been resolved with the addition of a ProxyAuthSecurityHandler available to Apache Wink client developers.

[1]: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WINK-292 *Apache Wink JIRA issue WINK-292*